# How to flatten warped louvered doors?

Tags: wood, doors

I reinstalled some louver doors which had been stored in the basement for a while. Its a double-door pair.

Possibly because of the position in which they were stored, or perhaps humidity, they have warped a bit.

This photo shows the difference at the bottom of the doors when they are evenly closed at the top:

[image]

So that's like 1-1/2" over the length of the doors (about 80").

[image]

The jamb material is about 5/8" thick and 3-1/2" deep.

It seems like both doors are actually warped a bit, but contrary to each other which doubles the effect. The hinge side is OK - or at least by fastening them to the jambs again, the hinge sides were straightened out.

I'm looking for advice on how to flatten these out. I can actually twist them just by hand, but they basically spring back. I'm concerned about breaking something by going too far with that.

Comment: Can you take the picture a little closer? :)

Comment: @DMoore at least I managed to keep my feet out of it :)

Comment: Touche... take one from about 3 feet back to see what kind of door frame we are working with.

Comment: @DMoore sorry I was being obtuse about the point you were making - will add another photo in a min.

Comment: @DMoore added another pic